# linear fit by group in apply takes too long using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe imported from a csv file. I need to do a linear fit using two or more columns defined by the user in a ';' string, one of the dataframe columns defines the grouping. The code is straight forward:

```
    from pandas import DataFrame
    from sklearn import linear_model

    def fit(data, x_names, y_name, fit_by):
        x_names = x_names.split(sep=';')
        data['_out_'] = data[y_name]  #may need to create equation later
        data.replace([inf, -inf], nan, inplace=True)
        data.dropna(subset=x_names, inplace=True)
        phi = data.groupby(fit_by).apply(lambda x: fit_group_func(x, x_names))
        phi.reset_index(inplace=True)
        phi = phi.pivot(index=fit_by, columns='level_1', values=0)
        phi.reset_index(inplace=True)
        x_names.insert(0, fit_by)
        phi.columns = x_names
        return phi

    def fit_group_func(df, x_names):
        model = linear_model.BayesianRidge()
        return DataFrame(model.fit(df[x_names], df['_out_']).coef_.tolist())
```

This code works pretty well when the data has 147830 rows, I mean no complaint on time used. The problem happens with 1881201 rows, it's really slow and nothing got returned after 2 hours so I killed the task.

I also noticed that my processor was being used as expected (15% one core) until I reached the fit_group_func when it dropped to zero and from time to time it became 1% and dropped again.

Note: I changed the code to have a function when fitting but nothing better happened. previously the line read:

```
        phi = data.groupby(fit_by).apply(lambda x: DataFrame(model.fit(x[x_names], x['_out_']).coef_.tolist())
```

Can somebody help me to figure out how to optimize this code and make it faster? I'm currently trying to run it on a Windows PC with 32 GB RAM and 8 cores processor. I also have access to a 96 GB RAM with 20 cores processor, but I don't think my problem is on the number of cores or RAM unless I can run the code in multiprocessor mode or something.

Comment: Use [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/1.0b3) and decorate `fit` with `@profile`, run it with the smaller data set and report back which lines take the most time.

Comment: Thanks Philip I'll do that. Just to let you know, just now I partitioned some of the data in chucks of 1GB each and they execute normally until one of them where the processor utilization goes to zero and gets stuck there. I'll play with the dataset a little more until I find out what is making it fail and don't return error.

Comment: For some reason ipython was unable to process after some count, but I updated some packages and python itself and now it doens't hang on the group.apply line. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. I ran the script on a linux box with a new anaconda python installation and it had no errors, so upgraded many packages and the problem went away.

For information purposes ipython hanged when using WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3, after upgrading packages it worked (not sure which one as I upgraded many of them). At last I installed WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0 and the problem is not there either.